# USB key behaves as a CD

Tags: command-line, usb, copy-paste, remote-disc

My USB key behaves as a CD, because I'm not able to copy a `.dmg`  file from my MacBook Pro 2016 with `sudo dd if=/Users/jeremiegauthier/Downloads/ubuntu-gnome-16.10-desktop-amd64.dmg of=/dev/rdisk2 or with the following method :

[image]

Could anyone be able to tell what I need to do to allow the access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to precede the `dd` command with `sudo` to give you permission.

I provide this answer with some reluctance because using `dd` is **extremely risky**. You can easily overwrite your system if you use the incorrect target. If you do not already know how to use `sudo` on the command line, you should look for other image copying tools, with inbuilt safeguards.